# I do not have a lot of money. Otherwise, I would have quit my job last year. - "otherwise" after a negative statement?

Tags: usage

**Example 1**

> I do not have a lot of money. Otherwise, I would quit my job.

**Example 2**

> I do not have a lot of money. Otherwise, I would have quit my job last year.

Can "otherwise" follow a negative statement?

Are the two examples correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Answer (score 2):

Both example 1 and Example 2 in the question are grammatically valid, and a fluent speaker might well say or write either. There is nothing about the word "otherwise" which says that it cannot follow a negative statement. For example:

> - John is not a quick thinker. Otherwise he would be more successful in our lunch Jeopardy games.

> - Frances is not patient in policy discussions. Otherwise she would find her views accepted more often.